# Story about a multiverse theory of immortality

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, parallel-universe

Please help me identify a short story I read about a guy who believed that the multiverse was true, but the one that we experienced was the one in which we lived the longest. He was also contemplating suicide, and every time he sat staring at the pills he was going to use to overdose, parallel universes (where he chose suicide) collapsed and the one he was in got weirder. Eventually an asteroid hit the Earth, and then he was resurrected somehow in the deep future.

I'm not sure where I read it, but it likely appeared in Dozois's *The Year's Best Science Fiction* or in a back issue of *Analog* (my dad had like a decade's worth in the den).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

["Divided By Infinity"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?84491) by [Robert Charles Wilson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Charles_Wilson), I'm pretty sure. It's (legally) online [on Tor's website](http://www.tor.com/stories/2010/08/divided-by-infinity).

Comment: Oh, man, I'm pretty certain this is it. And it was in the 16th _Year's Best_, which was 1999, which sounds about right. Wow, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the link; this was a wonderful story!

Comment: Definitely right, now that I've had a chance to read it. And way WAY darker than I remembered. Thanks!