# A story about a man whose wife recently passed, living into a least plausible reality

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading the entire story online.

The man ends up at an old bookstore that sells pulp scifi that his wife liked, realizes some of the titles are fake. The owner gives him a cryptic book and disappears (dies?). The book is (potentially portrayed as pseudoscience) about how we don't die, simply continue jumping into the least plausible reality.

He gets into an accident shortly after, and the story culminates decades (much longer?) later, with an alien species finding/using him as a repository of information about our species?

Comment: Could it be ["Divided by Infinity"](http://www.tor.com/2010/08/05/divided-by-infinity/) by Robert Charles Wilson? That was the subject of [this old question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60960/looking-for-a-short-story-one-man-is-lucky-enough-to-live-forever-through-coi) and [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32920/story-about-a-multiverse-theory-of-immortality).

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate question, but actually I think this is a better question than the previous two as it describes the story better. @user14111 it might be worth posting your comment as an answer and keeping this question open.

Comment: @JohnRennie Done. Now what do we do, close the **old** questions about this story??

Comment: @user14111: I'd just leave it to the mods to sort out.

Comment: Voted to reopen as the current one isn't accepted

Answer (score 3):

["Divided by Infinity"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?84491) by [Robert Charles Wilson](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?308), full text at [Tor.com](http://www.tor.com/2010/08/05/divided-by-infinity/).

This story was the subject of [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60960/looking-for-a-short-story-one-man-is-lucky-enough-to-live-forever-through-coi) and [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32920/story-about-a-multiverse-theory-of-immortality).

In fact there is a microgenre of [quantum immortality fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_suicide_and_quantum_immortality_in_fiction).