# Has science fiction used the Many Worlds Interpretation (MWI) of Hugh Everett to address time travel?

Tags: time-travel

The Many Worlds Interpretation (MWI) of quantum theory first proposed by Hugh Everett in 1957, says that everything that can happen, will, in its own separate universe.  (Note that this is not the multiverse, aka the megaverse theory.  Each universe of the multiverse, in the MWI, repeatedly branches **at the quantum level** and becomes many universes.)  Has any SF work explicitly used MWI to address time travel?

"Many-worlds implies that all possible alternate histories and futures are real, each representing an actual "world" (or "universe"). In lay terms, the hypothesis states there is a very large — perhaps infinite — number of universes, and everything that could possibly have happened in our past, but did not, has occurred in the past of some other universe or universes."  Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation

Comment: How do you apply that to time travel, specifically? There are quite a lot of stories that feature the "anything that can happen will have happened in an alternate universe/dimension" trope.

Comment: There are stories / continuums where time travel *creates* a parallel universe. Star Trek 2009, for instance.

Comment: Alternate historical worlds have been around a lot longer than 1957, specifically Murray Leinster's "Sideways in Time"

Comment: @Politank The creation of a parallel universe was one of the effects I was thinking about -- also the removal of the "kill your grandfather" paradox.

Comment: Essentially, yes: http://anathem.wikia.com/wiki/Polycosmic_Manipulation But, Neal Stephenson's book *Anathem* doesn't use normal English terms for such stuff. For instance, in the *Anathem* cosmos they have the Adrakhonic Theorem instead of the Pythagorean Theorem. You won't find the term Many Worlds Interpretation in the book, but there is mention of universes branching even at the quantum level (IIRC). And [Rhetors](http://anathem.wikia.com/wiki/Rhetor), a group of people that could utilize this theory, were said to be able to alter the past.

Comment: @Keen - I don't think this should have been put on hold since it's just asking if there exists *any* stories using the many-worlds interpretation, not asking for a list--see the [top answer](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/1467/22250) to [this question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/are-questions-looking-to-simply-prove-or-disprove-a-premise-with-a-yes-no-answer) in meta.

Comment: The 1998 novelette ["Divided by Infinity"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?84491) by Robert Charles Wilson, which you can read at [Tor.com](http://www.tor.com/2010/08/05/divided-by-infinity/?layout=print) (and which was the subject of [this old question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95098/a-story-about-a-man-whose-wife-recently-passed-living-into-a-least-plausible-re/95126#95126) among others) is about the MWI and "quantum immortality", but I don't recall any time travel.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Per the [FAQ](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), "Who wrote about topic Y?"-style questions are off-topic.

Comment: @Keen - I think you are misinterpreting that phrase, it's given as an example of "Questions calling for a **list** of works, authors", indicating to me that it's intended to mean "give me a **list** of authors who wrote about topic Y", not "is there any author who wrote about topic Y". If one interpreted it as broadly as you seem to be doing, then "who was the first author to write about Y" would also be off-topic, yet such questions are generally left open (examples [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins)).

Comment: The 1963 novelette ["Flux"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?66957) by Michael Moorcock and Barrington J. Bayley may be an example of what you're looking for. MWI is not mentioned but I guess it could be the underlying theory; I wouldn't know, not a scientist.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I'm not misinterpreting anything. This question is cut from the exact same cloth, and if you read the comments, you can see the bike shed in action. That's why I closed it, that's why the close reason and help center blurb is there; these questions accumulate a ton of 'me too!' answers from everyone who has one more example to add to the pile.

Comment: @Keen - Well, you didn't really address my point about *why* I thought you were misinterpreting it--do you disagree that when the FAQ says "Who wrote about topic Y?" in italics, this is meant as an example of the general case of "Questions calling for a list of works, authors" which immediately preceded it? Or do you agree with that but think this question *is* asking for a list, in spite of the fact that it just asks for "any SF work" which seems to require only a single example?

Comment: (cont) I don't know what you mean by "the bike shed", but the fact that people add a lot of examples in comments doesn't seem relevant, since the same thing happens when people ask for the first story about topic Y (people having different ideas about a candidate answer). Finally, did you read the [meta question I linked to](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/are-questions-looking-to-simply-prove-or-disprove-a-premise-with-a-yes-no-answer)? Do you disagree there's a consensus there for allowing questions asking if a *single* example of a given type of story can be found?

Comment: @Hypnosifl It obviously is not saying 'hey list works like this!' but it's effective reaction has literally been the same.  The answer to 'is there a work with X?' is *always* 'yes'.  If in the present, it's 'no', then a few dozen words of writing can fix that by creating a story with X.

Comment: @Hypnosifl This is an oooooold discussion on meta.  See: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/411/culling-list-and-recommendation-questions http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16/are-list-questions-allowed http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/are-all-list-questions-off-topic etc.

Comment: @Keen - The meta discussions you link to are specifically about questions that *were* asking for a list, whereas the meta discussion I linked to was about questions that asked for *any* example of something. (I think it's usually implicit that they want published works of the type that would be listed on isfdb or imdb; would you find such questions more acceptable if this criterion was stated explicitly?) If you want to make a case that it's absurd to allow such questions, you should try to build consensus for this perspective on an appropriate meta thread, not override the current consensus.

Comment: @ab2 - Hugh Everett's son is a somewhat famous musician in the band *The Eels*.  There was a documentary made about father and son.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.depauw.edu/sfs/backissues/60/benford60art.htm) an article by science fiction writer Gregory Benford where he talks about how Everett's interpretation specifically inspired the time travel mechanics of his 1980 novel [*Timescape*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553297090):

> Still, I wondered how tachyons—which Einstein's special theory of
>   relativity clearly allowed—could fit into the world as we knew it. I
>   essayed an approach in a novelette in Epoch, an anthology of the
>   mid-1970s. Then over five years I wrote a novel, Timescape (published
>   1980), exploring the simplest situation I could imagine—discovery of
>   tachyons, and the first attempts to probe their properties and use.
>   Rather than the convenient Wellsian traveler, I used scientists as I
>   knew them, warts and all, doing what they would—trying to use the new
>   discovery to communicate something they cared about.
>
> But how to deal with the paradox? I had always rather liked another
>   theory which resolved the multiple-outcome property of conventional
>   quantum mechanics. This interpretation of quantum events supposes that
>   when a given particle, say, passes through a hole in a wall, it can go
>   in several directions. The wave-like property of matter says that the
>   same experiment, repeated many times, will give a pattern of impacts
>   on a far screen. The density of impacts corresponds to the probability
>   that a single particle would follow that trajectory and make that
>   impression. But a single particle's trajectory can't be predicted
>   precisely—we can only get the probability distribution.
>
> Enter a fresh view, due to Hugh Everett of Princeton in the 1950s.
>   Everett said that all the possible outcomes predicted by the
>   probability analysis of quantum mechanics are separately real. This
>   means that every time a particle passes through a hole, the entire
>   universe splits into many possible outcomes.
>
> Envision separable worlds peeling off from every microscopic event. In
>   our world, the particle smacks into the wall and that specific outcome
>   defines our world forever more. Other worlds simultaneously appear,
>   with a slightly different impact point. Every event generates great
>   handfuls of other worlds—a cosmic plentitude of astronomical
>   extravagance. I've often wondered whether Everett was influenced by
>   such SF stories as Murray Leinster's "Sidewise in Time" (1934).
>   Certainly he influenced later SF writers, including the Larry Niven of
>   "All the Myriad Ways" (1963).
>
> The Everett view was fun to think about, and logically defensible, but
>   nobody really believed it. But I found it handy. (Writers are
>   magpies.) I said in my novel that the Everett interpretation didn't
>   really apply to every event. Instead, I reserved the Everett picture
>   for only those events which produced a causal paradox. If a physicist
>   sent a tachyon backward in time and it had no grandfather-killing
>   effects, no problem. If it did, though, then the universe split into
>   as many versions as it took to cover all the possibilities. So you
>   could indeed send some grandfather-killing message (or anything else
>   that made a paradox), and grandfather would die. But not in the
>   universe you were doomed to inhabit. Instead, another universe would
>   appear, unknown to you, in which dear old grandfather died, alas, and
>   you never happened at all. No paradox, since the tachyon which killed
>   gramps came from another universe, from another you.

Searching inside the book on amazon shows it doesn't directly reference Everett or the many-worlds interpretation, but if you search in the book for the word "quantum" it does feature a character thinking about the problem of what causes the wave function to collapse in quantum mechanics (p. 211), and coming up with the idea that the paradoxes associated with tachyons (which travel faster than light and can therefore be used to transmit information back in time, see the [tachyonic antitelephone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_antitelephone)) could be solved if the wavefunction didn't collapse at all (p. 363):

> Markham thought of a universe with one wave function, scattering into the new states of being as a paradox formed inside it like the kernel of an idea.—If the wave function did not collapse ... Worlds lay ahead of him, and worlds lay behind.

For an example of a story where time travel creates branching histories that *does* explicitly reference Everett, there is [*The Time Ships*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061056480) by Stephen Baxter (an officially-licensed sequel to H.G. Wells' *The Time Machine*, published in 1995), where there is the following dialogue between the narrator and two other characters (in a section viewable [here](http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/147908/41/Baxter_-_The_Time_Ships.html)):

> “There is — will be — a new philosophy called the Many Worlds
>   Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics, “Nebogipfel said, and the sound
>   of his queer, liquid voice, delivering such a striking phrase, sent
>   shivers along my spine. “There is another ten or twenty years to
>   elapse before the crucial papers are published — I remember the name
>   of Everett…”
>
> “It’s like this,” Moses said. “Suppose you have a Particle which can
>   be in just two places — here or there, we will say — with some chance
>   associated with each place. All right? Now you take a look with your
>   microscope, and find it here…”
>
> “According to the Many Worlds idea,” Nebogipfel said, “History splits
>   into two when you perform such an experiment. In the other History,
>   there is another you — who has just found the object there, rather
>   than here.”
>
> “Another History?”
>
> Moses said, “With all the reality and consistency of this one.”
>
> He grinned. “There is another you there is an infinite number of
>   ’you’s’ — propagating like rabbits at every moment!”
>
> “What an appalling thought,” I said. “I thought two were more than
>   enough. But look, Nebogipfel, couldn’t we tell if we were being split
>   up in this way?”
>
> “No,” he said, “because any such measurement, in either History, would
>   have to come after the split. It would be impossible to measure the
>   consequences of the split itself.”
>
> “Would it be possible to detect if these other Histories were there? —
>   or for me to travel there, to meet another of this sheaf of twin
>   selves you say I have?”
>
> “No,” Nebogipfel said. “Quite impossible. Unless—”
>
> “Yes?”
>
> “Unless some of the tenets of Quantum Mechanics prove to be false.”
>
> Moses said, “You can see why these ideas could help us make sense of
>   the paradoxes we have uncovered. If more than one History can indeed
>   exist—”
>
> “Then causality violations are easily dealt with,” Nebogipfel said.
>   “Look: suppose you had returned through time with a gun, and shot
>   Moses summarily.” Moses paled a little at this.
>
> Nebogipfel went on: “So there we have a classic Causality Paradox in
>   its simplest terms. If Moses is dead, he will not go on to build the
>   Time Machine, and become you — and so he cannot travel back in time to
>   do the murder. But if the murder does not take place, Moses lives on
>   to build the machine, travels back — and kills his younger self. And
>   then he cannot build the machine, and the murder cannot be committed,
>   and—”
>
> “Enough,” I said. “I think we understand.”
>
> “It is a pathological failure of causality,” Nebogipfel said, “a loop
>   without termination.
>
> “But if the Many Worlds idea is right, there is no paradox. History
>   splits in two: in one edition, Moses lives; in the second, he dies.
>   You, as a Time Traveler, have simply crossed from one History into the
>   other.”
>
> “I see it,” I said in wonder. “And surely this Many Worlds phenomenon
>   is precisely what we have witnessed, Nebogipfel and I — we have
>   already watched the unfolding of more than one edition of History…” I
>   felt enormously reassured by all this — for the first time, I saw that
>   there might be a glimmer of logic about the blizzard of conflicting
>   Histories which had hailed about my head since my second launch into
>   time! Finding some sort of theoretical structure to explain things was
>   as important to me as finding solid ground beneath his feet might be
>   to a drowning man; though what practical application we might make of
>   all this I could not yet imagine.

Also worth noting is that the idea of time travel paradoxes being solved by having multiple parallel histories actually predates Everett's theory. On p. 299 of his book [*Time Machines*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387985719), Paul Nahin writes:

> The first such tale in science fiction was probably the 1935 story "The Branches of Time" (Daniels), which also contained the observation that although alternate time tracks may allow for changing the past for the better (something that can't be done, for better *or* for worse, with just one time time track), in the end any such change may still be futile. As Daniels' time traveler puts it, sadly, "I did have an idea to ... go back to make past ages more liveable. Terrible things have happened in history, you know. But it isn't any use. Think, for instance, of the martyrs and the things they suffered. I could go back and save them those wrongs. And yet all the time ... they would still have known their unhappiness and their agony, because in this world-line those things have happened. At the end, it's all unchangeable; it merely unrolls before us."

And endnote to this section on p. 400 adds:

> The editorial introduction to this pioneering tale is interesting; the opening line is "To say that this short story contains some revolutionary time-travel theories would be putting it exceedingly mild." The editor then goes on to tell us enthusiastically that "when the author ... submitted this story to us, his accompanying letter stated that in it he had settled the time-travel question once and for all. We must admit that a broad, unbelieving grin spread over our countenances when the author dared to make this assertion. BUT—the smile soon left our faces. ... [T]o our chagrin, Mr. Daniels had really propounded so many brand new ideas about time and time-travel, and such logical ones—*that he has not left one loophole in his argument!*" ... After Daniels the concept quickly became part of standard science fiction lore and could be used by writers with little explanation. For example, in the 1947 story "A Hitch in Time" (MacCreigh) the author did not have to say much about his "First Law of Chronistics," which determines the development of "the branches of Fan-Shaped time." It was sufficient for his readers to learn that should a time traveler to the past change anything, a parallel branch of time would be created on which the time traveler would be trapped. "The man who interfered with the space-time matrix, displacing even a comma in the great scroll of time, would be cut off from his origin forever."

"The Branches of Time" appeared in the August 1935 issue of *Wonder Stories*, which is available on archive.org [here](http://archive.org/details/Wonder_Stories_v07n03_1935-08) (the story starts on page 295), part of their [pulp magazine archive](http://archive.org/details/pulpmagazinearchive?sort=titleSorter). There are also alternate history stories that predate "The Branches of Time", such as Leinster's ["Sideways in Time"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidewise_in_Time) from 1934 (on archive.org [here](http://archive.org/details/Astounding_v13n04_1934-06), p. 10) which was mentioned by Oldcat in a comment (see [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternate_history#History_of_alternate_history_literature) for more examples), but "The Branches of Time" may be the first in which new alternate histories are created directly by time travel, and only begin to diverge from our history at the moment the time traveler arrives in the past.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. It's more -- and better -- than I hoped to get.  I'll have to find copies of "Timescape" and "The Time Ships."

Answer (score 1):

Actually the Apocalypse Troll by David Weber mentions the theory specifically(though not Everett)

[image: Apocalypse Trol]

Comment: I'll have to get a copy.